# Build a solution file using msbuild on windows 32 bit system

Tags: qt, msbuild

I am asked to build a qt based solution file using msbuild.I tried with a below command and i am ending up in getting a error.I could able to build a wix project with same command shown below.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>MSBuild "C:\path\to\my solution file\my.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32
```

With these, i am getting a error saying,

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5):
error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3. [c:\my\path to\project file\my.vcxproj]
```

The paths of various files in my.vcxproj are not read by the system when Moc'ing.I get the below error

```
InitializeBuildStatus:
    Touching "Win32\Release\my.unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
    Moc'ing "dialog.h"...
    The system cannot find the file path specified
    Moc'ing "Centralwidget.h"...
    The system cannot find the file path specified
```

and so on....

I have tried to build using qmake too,but not succeeded.Looking forward for the good suggestion for which method to use to build a qt based solution file.Thanks in advance

Comment: What's inside `my.vcxproj`? Add relevant sections from your .vcxproj to your question, as well as detailed output of the error message produced by MSBuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a Qt solution file using MSBuild,

```
def buildsolution(self,solutionpath):
    if not os.path.isfile(self.msbuild):
        raise Exception('MSBuild.exe not found. path=' + self.msbuild)
    arg1 = '/t:Rebuild'
    arg2 = '/p:Configuration=Release'
    arg3 = '/p:Platform=Win32'
    proc = subprocess.Popen(([self.msbuild,solutionpath,arg1,arg2,arg3]), shell=True, 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()                        
        wx.Yield()
        if not line: break
    proc.wait()
```

Where **self.msbuild=r'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe'** and
      **solutionpath=r'path to\qt solution file\my.sln'**